# Inputting a Json object into a mongodb using meteor

Tags: json, mongodb, meteor

I'm attempting to insert an API response into my mongo db, but it doesn't save the individual fields.

Input here

```
PlayersList.insert(Meteor.http.get("API CALL HERE"));
```

Here is the response from the call:

```
{"hnub": {
   "id": 21098134,
   "name": "Hnub",
   "profileIconId": 20,
   "revisionDate": 1428613578000,
   "summonerLevel": 30
}}
```

Is there a simple way to do this cleanly saving all the fields?

Comment: Something like `PlayersList.insert(Meteor.http.get("API CALL HERE")["hnub"]);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response of an HTTP call is an object with content (String), data (JavaScript Object if it can be parsed as JSON), headers, and statusCode. I recommend that you run some code like this to see the actual response:

```
console.log(Meteor.HTTP.get("API CALL HERE"));
```

If it turns out that response includes parsed JSON under the data field, then you could accomplish what you want with:

```
PlayersList.insert(Meteor.HTTP.get("API CALL HERE").data);
```

Note, this synchronous way of making an API call will only work from the server. As @Ethaan points out, you'll need to use a callback to do it from the client and you'll have to overcome cross domain restrictions.

Comment: Thank you very much I was performing this on the server so .data works well

Answer (score 1):

You should do the inset into the callback not like that.

check the syntaxis `HTTP.get(url, [callOptions], [asyncCallback])`

> Callback that is called when the request is completed. Required on the
>   client.

from [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_get).

So try with.

```
Meteor.http.get(url,function(err,result){
 if(!err){
  PlayersList.insert({result})
  }
})
```

Be sure you have `$ meteor add http`, if this don't work for some `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` policy use  [Meteor.method](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods)/[Meteor.call](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call)